# Change parameters block-wise in experiment design?

Tags: experiment-design, blocking, split-plot

Is it possible to generate an experiment design which changes a parameter block-wise?
To be more precise what I would like to do:

Run an experiment with a certain parameter (humidity) fixed which is rather hard to control but change that parameter in a block in an addition block afterwards.

Background: I wanna' test some devices which have to be measured by varying different physical parameters like temperature, humidity and so on.
In this way I can already have a look at the data after the first block and maybe decide that I don't have to continue. When the data looks promising I would continue with the additional block where I'll vary that tough parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for split-plot design. The name comes from agricultural land experiments where there is a treatment that have to be applied at large plots of land, an example could be fumigation by aircraft. Then those large plots are further split in smaller plots where other treatments are applied. Your difficult-to-vary variable corresponds to the large plot, to your block.

You didn't give much detail, so I cannot say more now. If you want further advice please add more details to your post.

An afterthought: If this is an industrial operation, you might benefit from [evolutionary operation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2985505.pdf?casa_token=6DSy2-jcutMAAAAA:gCHpO0bZxa8yREi6TGicmC7AscgQARv80Yuf0DcoJ9-I6XX9_PpZNpH5MSQ32zZnyQ_X3PQmUTBdSwmM9LpKzFCjGRDtR_l9Wgrnxu_GLf77orl1tj6wPw).  Also [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EVOP).

Comment: perfect, thank you! Just to settle: Which further information could you give? Or in other words: Which additional details do you need for which further information? :) From my pov you answered my question but maybe there is something more I could benefit from?