# How to compare and evaluate different business concepts?

Tags: experiment-design, marketing, business-intelligence

Don't ask me how exactly I came up with this question but I wonder about the following:

Assume you want to compare different offers in how requested (and/or how profitable) they are. In addition, due to limited space, they can only be used once at a location. But there are multiple ones.

To simplify, let's say there are three locations (A, B and C) and we have three offers (soccer, football and golf).
I would start with assigning them arbitrarily: A-> soccer, B-> football, C-> golf.
Is it possible to figure out how successfull they are compared with each other by taking into account or disregarding the factor of the certain locations?

A remedy would be to swap the offerings for a certain period of time. But then we also have seasonal influences like summer and winter or so.
Does someone know how businesses study such thoughts? Or do you even know certain methods to apply?

Comment: Try to make a concrete example: Locations, offers, define relevant seasons ... start with a factorial design, look into [optimal design](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=optimal+experi*+design++answers%3A1), but I guess businesses will want a cost function also counting profits ... Maybe evolutionary operation?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490698/change-parameters-block-wise-in-experiment-design/490847#490847

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Do you know, by chance, if the marketing departments of e.g. Coca Cola or so also perform experiment designs for such purposes?
I'm fine with that as it makes sense to me and I'm kind of used to it. I also don't know what to do instead, A/B tests are too simple in this context I guess. Nevertheless I never heard much about marketing/business and statistics :)